# How to bind attributes with v-bind only once?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-i18n

I am using [vue-i18n](https://github.com/kazupon/vue-i18n) for localization. When I want to translate input placeholders, as in:

`<input type="text" v-model="someValue" :placeholder="$t('translation.string')">`

I have to use the `$t()` function which is executed on every re-render ([library docs mention](https://kazupon.github.io/vue-i18n/en/directive.html#object-syntax) is as well). This adds thousands of unnecessary function calls in my simple booking form, which I'd like to avoid.

Is there a way to bind the attribute only once? The translated value does not change throughout the lifecycle of Vue instance. `v-once` is not what I am looking for, since I want to keep the component/node reactive, and only 'hardcode' the attribute.

I know I could achieve what I need by simply storing the translated strings in the data object, but I'd like to know if there is an alternative, simpler solution (not requiring massive code duplication).

Comment: Create a data property which you initialize with your translation, then pass that to  `:placeholder`.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Is there any other way? I mentioned in my question that I am looking for solutions not involving storing the translated values in the data object.

Comment: Yes, with mustache syntax it doesn't even compile - I get the `Interpolation inside attributes has been removed.` error.

Comment: `v-t` directive works only with text content, not with attributes, unfortunately. I thought about somehow getting the value out of where the directive stores it, but couldn't find a way :/

Comment: That documentation link went the way of the dodo, here's the updated link: <https://kazupon.github.io/vue-i18n/guide/directive.html#t>.

Answer (score 2):

A [`computed` property](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#computed) will do what you're looking for, since they only trigger a re-run when their dependencies change. Since `this.$t('LOCALE.STRING')` doesn't change unless your locale changes, you're *guaranteed* only a single run, after which the value will be cached by Vue for subsequent renders.

```html
<template>
  ...
  <input
    ...
    :placeholder="translatedPlaceholder"
  >
  ...
</template>

<script>
  ...
  computed: {
    translatedPlaceholder() {
      return $t('translation.string');
    },
  },
  ...
</script>
```

The awesome part about this solution is that if the locale *does* change, then Vue will indeed refresh the computed property, updating it to the correct value.

---

I've put together an interactive snippet to help demonstrate this syntax, if you're looking for a more extensive example.

The snippet includes a simple localized greeting followed by a random number in a `<p>` tag, with two buttons. The localized string in the text is pulled from a computed property.

The first button will generate a new number, causing the `<p>` to re-render in the DOM.
The second button will switch the locale, causing Vue-i18n to refresh the localized string.

Whenever the computed localization property is re-executed, it will log to console.
I also set the script up to log to console whenever Vue updates the DOM too.

```js
const messages = {
  en: {
    "greeting": 'Hello!',
  },
  es: {
    "greeting": '¡Hola!',
  },
};

new Vue({ 
  i18n: new VueI18n({
    locale: 'en',
    messages,
  }),
  data() {
    return {
      num: 1,
    }
  },
  computed: {
    localizedGreeting() {
      console.log('Computed executed');
      return this.$t('greeting');
    },
  },
  methods: {
    swapLocale() {
      this.$i18n.locale = (this.$i18n.locale == 'en' ? 'es' : 'en');
    },
    randomNum() {
      this.num = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10000);
    },
  },
  updated() {
    console.log('DOM updated');
  },
}).$mount('#app')
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  max-height: 120px !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2/dist/vue.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue-i18n@8"></script>

<div id="app">
  <p>{{ `${localizedGreeting} #${num}` }}</p>
  <button @click="randomNum()">Re-render Greeting</button>
  <button @click="swapLocale">Swap Greeting Locale</button>
</div>
```

As you can see, re-rendering *doesn't* cause the computed property to re-execute, but swapping the locale *does*, which is exactly what we're looking for here.

---

As a final note– while there is technically a performance hit in your original code, since you're re-executing `$t()` calls, it's worth bearing in mind that the actual performance hit is probably *tiny*. Don't trade simplicity for performance gains unless it really makes sense.

Remember, **[premature optimization is the root of all evil](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/80084/is-premature-optimization-really-the-root-of-all-evil/80092#80092)**!